# Redis - How to use async MULTI?

Tags: redis

We are using hiredis from our C++ application using the redisAsyncCommandArgv interface. What we are not able to figure out is how to execute a bunch of commands in a MULTI-EXEC transaction. The redisAsyncCommandArgv encodes only one command at a time. Can it be used to send all the commands in a transaction in one go? Synchronous API is straight forward but, they cannot be used.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to use `MULTI-EXEC` over Redis Asynchronous API. You can only choose one.

`MULTI-EXEC` transactions SHOULD always execute sequentially. Redis Asynchronous API, on the other hand, allows the commands to be delivered out of order. Hence, it won't make sense to make a `MULTI-EXEC` transaction if the commands aren't in the proper sequence or worse, if `MULTI` and `EXEC` commands themselves became out of order.